# gdrive upload fails with "Token has been expired or revoked." if it is executed with crontab but works as root (sudo -s)

Tags: cron, token, root, sudo, gdrive

I have written a script that uploads/updates an image to my gdrive. It should be executed every 15 min by a crontab entry.

I tested the script as root (sudo -s) and it works and has access to my gdrive. But it does not work when started by my crontab entry. I then get the following message as an error.

```
Uploading upload.jpg
Failed to upload file: Patch https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/1y0000hMVV444qjuxC5xqL3hsmyAuoXya?alt=json&fields=id%2Cname%2Csize&uploadType=multipart: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```

This is my crontab entry

```
*/15  * * * *   root    /srv/media/webcam/nordbahnstrasse/scripts/upload_image.sh     >> /var/log/upload_image.txt
```

Comment: Man you should change the default config folder with `-c` parameter e.g I'm running it via php exec with `gdrive -c /root/.gdrive/ --service-account "dcvcdewe.json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gdrive command checks a token stored in **token_v2.json**. The default location for that file is within the user's home.

```
$HOME/.gdrive/token_v2.json
```

Using sudo -s changes the user, but the variable $HOME still points to the original user. Running a command with crontab as root checkes for `/root/.gdrive/token_v2.json`

So the solution is to copy the file `token_v2.json` to `/root/.gdrive/token_v2.json`